# How to include Processing.js code in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, processing

I want to write a processing.js script for my webpage, but my sketch doesn't show up. I included the following lines :

```
<canvas id="mycanvas'></canvas>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/processing.js/1.4.8/processing.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var sketchProc = function(processingInstance) {
     with (processingInstance) {
        size(400, 400);
        frameRate(30);

        // ProgramCodeGoesHere
        fill(255, 255, 0);
        ellipse(200, 200, 200, 200);
        noFill();
        stroke(0, 0, 0);
        strokeWeight(2);
        arc(200, 200, 150, 100, 0, PI);
        fill(0, 0, 0);
        ellipse(250, 200, 10, 10);
        ellipse(153, 200, 10, 10);
    }};

    // Get the canvas that Processing-js will use
    var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
    // Pass the function sketchProc (defined in myCode.js) to Processing's constructor.
    var processingInstance = new Processing(canvas, sketchProc);
 </script>
```

I don't see any error messages, so I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Typo in `id="mycanvas'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: in the first line, change id="mycanvas' to either id="mycanvas" or id='mycanvas' (don't mix them up). Hope this helps! 
Greetings from another newbie ;)

Comment: sorry, @BrightFaith appears to have been quicker with the same answer

Answer (score 1):

Please try adding dimensions on your canvas

```
<canvas id="mycanvas" style:"height:400px; width:400px"></canvas>
```

or CSS style

```
<style>
#mycanvas {
  height:400px;
  width:400px;
}
</style>


canvas "'" also has syntax error.
```

Answer (score 0):

because you have an error in your html

> `<canvas id="mycanvas'></canvas>`

your  canvas id begins with `"` and ends with `'`
change it to

> `<canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>`

and it should be fixed